# Python: Page never loads, no syntax errors

Tags: python, html, jinja2, app.yaml

I created a simple web page in Python, using Jinja2. When I run my code in the browser, the page just says loading, but never loads. I have jinja2 installed, and I have my front.html file in a templates folder.

My log shows:

```
WARNING  2014-02-21 14:17:49,151 api_server.py:341] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2014-02-21 14:17:49,164 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http://localhost:49824
INFO     2014-02-21 14:17:49,168 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:11001
INFO     2014-02-21 14:17:49,171 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8004
```

My app.yaml file:

```
application: ascii
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: asciichan.app
- url: /templates
  script: front.html

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

My Python file:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                               autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class MainPage(Handler):
    def render_front(self, title="", art="", error=""):
        self.render("front.html", title=title, art=art, error=error)

    def get(self):
        self.render_front()

    def post(self):
        title = self.request.get("title")
        art = self.request.get("art")

        if title and art:
            self.write("thanks!")
        else:
            error = "we need both a title and some artwork!"
            self.render_front(title, art, error)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug = True)
```

My front.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>/ascii/</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>/ascii/</h1>

        <form method = "post">
            <label>
                <div>title</div>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="{{title}}">
            </label>

            <label>
                <div>art</div>
                <textarea name="art">{{art}}</textarea>
            </label>

            <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Sorry this is so long, but I'm confused about what the problem could be. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what url are you going to?

Comment: Just running from my localhost, no specific url yet.

Comment: I have other projects (I'm using Google App Engine) that all give me the same PIL module warning in the log, but those work fine. It's just this project that won't load.

Comment: Which port of url you are going to?

Comment: Try this `http://localhost:8080/`

Comment: I tried it just now, I get a "No data received" message.

Comment: If the name of your Python file is: asciichan.py the app should work. You do no need in the app.yaml: - url: /templates
  script: front.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says your default server is at:

```
http://localhost:11001

INFO     2014-02-21 14:17:49,168 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running  at: http://localhost:11001
```

However going to:

```
http://localhost:11001/
```

would require you to have an def index in your asciichan.py file.  Try this in your browser:

```
http://localhost:11001/MainPage
```

Hope this helps!